# Problems with Minimax implementation in javascript for connect 4

Tags: javascript, algorithm, minimax

I was attempting to create a ai to play against the human player through the minimax (alpha-beta) algorithm, unfortunately I have had an error I cant figure out. Here is the general error message:

Cannot set property NaN of undefined at the function Disc.lock, called from play, called from alpha-beta

I checked all the code surrounding the error at which the line was in and changing variable declarations, but that didn't change anything.

Is there any way to fix this, or any code that I can change that will help stop this problem?

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
const rows = 6;
const columns = 7;

function Disc(player, x) {
  this.player = player;
  this.x = x;
  this.draw = function () {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, 31, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    c.fillStyle = player;
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
    c.fillStyle;
  }
  this.lock = function (board) {
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      if (board[i][Math.floor(this.x / 70)] != "white") {
        board[i - 1][Math.floor(this.x / 70)] = this.player;
        return;
      }
    }
    board[rows - 1][Math.floor(this.x / 70)] = player;
  }
}


function availSpots(board) {
  availableSpots = [];
  for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    if (board[0][i] == "white") {
      availableSpots.push(i);
    }
  }
  return availableSpots;
}

function isWin(board, player) {
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < columns - 3; j++) {
      if (
        board[i][j] == player &&
        board[i][j + 1] == player &&
        board[i][j + 2] == player &&
        board[i][j + 3] == player
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rows - 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      if (
        board[i][j] == player &&
        board[i + 1][j] == player &&
        board[i + 2][j] == player &&
        board[i + 3][j] == player
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rows - 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < columns - 3; j++) {
      if (
        board[i][j] == player &&
        board[i + 1][j + 1] == player &&
        board[i + 2][j + 2] == player &&
        board[i + 3][j + 3] == player
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rows - 3; i++) {
    for (j = 3; j < columns; j++) {
      if (
        board[i][j] == player &&
        board[i + 1][j - 1] == player &&
        board[i + 2][j - 2] == player &&
        board[i + 3][j - 3] == player
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function isTerminalNode(node) {
  return isWin(node, "blue") || isWin(node, "red") || availSpots(node).length == 0;
}

function play(node, move, maximizingPlayer) {
  let boardCopy = [];
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    boardCopy.push([0]);
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      boardCopy[i][j] = node[i][j]
    }
  }
  if (maximizingPlayer) {
    player = "red";
  } else if (!maximizingPlayer) {
    player = "blue";
  }
  discCopy = new Disc(player, move * 70);
  discCopy.lock(boardCopy);
  return boardCopy;
}

function alphabeta(node, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer) {
  spots = availSpots(node);

  if (isTerminalNode(node)) {
    if (isWin(node, "red")) {
      return { score: 10, move: undefined };
    } else if (isWin(node, "blue")) {
      return { score: -10, move: undefined };
    } else if (spots.length == 0) {
      return { score: 0, move: undefined };
    }
  }

  if (maximizingPlayer) {
    value = -Infinity;
    for (move in spots) {
      child = play(node, spots[move], true);
      temporaryMax = alphabeta(child, alpha, beta, false).score;
      if (temporaryMax > value) {
        value = temporaryMax;
        bestMove = spots[move];
      }
      alpha = Math.max(alpha, value);
      if (beta <= alpha) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return { score: value, move: bestMove };
  } else {
    value = Infinity;
    for (move in spots) {
      child = play(node, spots[move], false);
      temporaryMin = alphabeta(child, alpha, beta, true).score;
      if (temporaryMin < value) {
        value = temporaryMin;
        bestMove = spots[move];
      }
      beta = Math.min(beta, value);
      if (alpha <= beta) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return { score: value, move: bestMove };
  }
}
```

Comment: NaN means not a number. In your `Disc.lock` function, `i` is a number. Which leaves `Math.floor(this.x/70)`. My questions would be: **Do you definitely set this.x?** You'll need to work backwards through your code, console logging values to work it out. Also, `rows` sounds like its undefined

Comment: By console logging the input values of x, it seems to be clearly defined, but the problem seems to occur after a few times calling the function.

Comment: where is `rows` defined?

Comment: Just to help, Disc.lock is declared in the play function.

Comment: In the snippet of code I am showing you, it is not defined, but in the full program, rows is a number declared on the top. If you wan't any additional code, feel free to ask.

Comment: The lock function is to drop a piece on the board.

Comment: if you `console.log(rows)` is it showing 6 correctly?

Comment: yes, it shows 6 properly.

Comment: if you put this `if((i-1) < 0){ console.log('i-1 is negative'); }` after `if (board[i][Math.floor(this.x / 70)] != "white") {` does anything log to the console?

Comment: Yes, it logs i - 1 is negative once.